# How can I run monero node in LAN?

Tags: monerod, blockchain

Sorry to bother. I'm new to Monero. Recently I followed this article (*https://github.com/moneroexamples/private-testnet#step-2-start-first-node*) to set up a private chain consist of three nodes. But this is not what I want.

There are three nodes:

node1:172.17.0.2:28080

node2:172.17.0.6:28080

node3:172.17.0.7:28080

**problem_1:** On node1, when I use option **--add-exclusive-node 172.17.0.6:28080**, I succeeded and block syncing function was normal. But when I use get_peer_list, nothing returned. It should have returned node2 I guess.

**problem_2:** I linked node1 and node2, node2 and node3. I think node1 should add node3 to its peer list but it didn't.

**problem_3:** When I use option **--add-peer 172.17.0.6:28080** on node1, nothing happened. I think its function should be the same as **--add-exclusive-node 172.17.0.6:28080** except the limitation of peers. And I want to use option **--add-peer** avoiding the DNS seed influence.

Please let me know if there is any missing information.

I will appreciate it if anyone could solve my problems QAQ. Thanks very much!!!!!

Comment: What are you setting for `--p2p-bind-ip` on each node?

Comment: Its own ip. To node1 , it is --p2p-bind-ip 172.17.0.2. By the way, I use docker to run these three nodes, so the ip begin with 172. @jtgrassie

Comment: And have you verified each container can reach/ping each other on those IPs?

Comment: Of course. This is the first step QAQ. @jtgrassie

Comment: You should be using `--add-exclusive-node` not `--add-peer` as you're attempting to run a private network. With all nodes adding *each other* as exclusive nodes, mine a block on one and you should see it getting broadcast to the others.

Comment: I'd also suggest updating your your question to include the exact command line of each node, as you obviously cannot simply copy the cited examples as they assume all nodes are running on the same host, not in docker containers.